# A stock market investor simulation

Tags: java, oop

I have to write a program that simulates an investor buying and selling shares in a stock market. The investor needs tools to display his portfolio and buy and sell shares. Shares value can go up and down so un underlying simulation of the market should be implemented.

There are 7 levels all must be done in stages:

Level 1 –Includes screen output and keyboard input and basic classes.
There are java source files for at least three major classes in the program.
Good source comments and code indentation is expected for all implemented parts of the code

Example: The program reads and prints the names of shares and their basic characteristics.

Level 2 – Includes methods and variables for at least three major classes, and all constructions above.

At least 3 major methods fully implemented and working for each class
Example: As above, but also the notion of the buying and sell shares is shown.

Level 3 – At least three major program classes will be implemented, with methods working and well designed,and all constructions above
Use of inheritance with at least one superclass and three subclasses
Class, method and variable naming will be clear and consistent

Example: As above, but also there is a basic simulation of the stock market, though most details, commentary etc. may be very simple

Level 4 –Polymorphism should be used in at least three subclasses, and all constructions above

At least four major program classes will be implemented, with methods working and well designed,Comments are clear and applied to class and method level consistently

Example: As above, but the simulation is more natural, there is a running commentary of the change in value of the
shares with major events reported.

Level 5 –Use of ArrayLists or other classes from Java’s Collection Framework in all parts of the program, and all constructions above.Exception handling is carried out appropriately in all parts of the program Inheritance is correctly applied to all parts of the program.

Example: As above, but all types of accounts and functionality will now be included in the simulation. The simulation is now mostly ruled by a basic GUI.

Level 6 – Includes file input and/or output, and all constructions above
The simulation (including player movement) will be displayed on the GUI Polymorphism will be fully implemented in all parts of the program

Example: As above, with a full GUI now controlling all aspects of the simulation; data should be read from files.

Level 7 – Includes everything required for an A grade but also something special (using other more advanced constructs or algorithms,
or something you just read up on yourself). Make it a program someone would really want to use!

Example: .. real historical data, moving averages,...

This is my code the error I get is array not found for the shares part:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StockMarketInvestor
{

    public StockMarketInvestor()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        String name;
        int numberShares;
        double buyPrice,sellPrice;
        create String; array

        String[] shares = new String[]{"ARM", "IBM", "Google", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Samsung", "Lenovo", "Intel"};

        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) Arrays.asList(shares);

        System.out.println("String array converted to List");

        for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Which share would you like to purchase?");
        name=input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How many shares bought?");
        numberShares=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Buy price?");
        buyPrice=input.nextDouble();       
        System.out.print("Sale price?");
        sellPrice=input.nextDouble();        
        input.close();       

        System.out.println(name + "here is the information of your stock transactions:");
        System.out.println("Number of shares:" + numberShares);        
        System.out.println("Amount of purchase:" + buyPrice*numberShares);      
        System.out.println("Amount of sell:" + sellPrice*numberShares);      
        System.out.println("Transaction fee paid:" + 15 + 15);
        System.out.println("Net profit:" + (sellPrice*numberShares-buyPrice));

    }

}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you focused on one specific problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you just use a simple Array, why do you need the extra step into converting from an Array to an ArrayList?

Iterating trough the list works just fine, as underneath:

```
public class StockMarketInvestor {

    public StockMarketInvestor() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        int numberShares;
        double buyPrice, sellPrice;

        String[] shares = new String[] { "ARM", "IBM", "Google", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Samsung", "Lenovo", "Intel" };

        System.out.println("Going trough the list: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < shares.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(shares[i]);
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Which share would you like to purchase?");
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How many shares bought?");
        numberShares = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Buy price?");
        buyPrice = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Sale price?");
        sellPrice = input.nextDouble();
        input.close();

        System.out.println(name + "here is the information of your stock transactions:");
        System.out.println("Number of shares:" + numberShares);
        System.out.println("Amount of purchase:" + buyPrice * numberShares);
        System.out.println("Amount of sell:" + sellPrice * numberShares);
        System.out.println("Transaction fee paid:" + 15 + 15);
        System.out.println("Net profit:" + (sellPrice * numberShares - buyPrice));

    }

}
```